# Returning a Random Number Type Problem

Tags: c#

I'm trying to return a random number from a method but apparently the implicit type is not correct. It says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Randomize.RandomNumber' to 'int'"

RandomNumber.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Randomizer
{
    class RandomNumber
    {
        public int RandomInRange(int l, int u)
        {
            Random generator = new Random();
            return generator.Next(l, u);
        }

    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Randomizer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Please enter the minimum range for the random number\n");
            int min = int.Parse(Console.In.ReadLine());

            Console.Out.WriteLine("Please enter the maximum range for the random number\n");
            int max = int.Parse(Console.In.ReadLine());

            int RandomInt = new RandomNumber();

            Console.Out.WriteLine("Your random number is: " + RandomInt.RandomInRange(min, max));

            Console.In.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

I know it's pretty much a noob question, but I'm used to C++. Thanks for the help in advance. =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just initializing an instance of the RandomNumber class.  You should be saying:

```
RandomNumber random = new RandomNumber();
int randomInt = random.RandomRange(min,max);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is important to note that you don't want to create a new Random every time. Also it looks like you want a static class by the way you are using it.

```
public static class RandomNumber
{
    private static readonly Random generator = new Random();

    public static int RandomInRange(int l, int u)
    {
        return generator.Next(l, u);
    }
}
```

Comment: An additional note: the reason you don't want to create a new Random every time is because Random is seeded off the *clock*. If you create two of these in the same clock time slice, they will produce *exactly the same numbers*.  Make Random ONCE in a static variable and keep on re=using the same Random, rather than making a new one every time.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("Your random number is: {0}" , RandomInt.RandomInR)
```

Is one possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if I'm missing something, but this:

```
int RandomInt = new RandomNumber();
```

should be:

```
RandomNumber RandomInt = new RandomNumber();
```

You're creating an instance of `RandomNumber`, not an `int`. To alleviate some headache in the future, you could also use C# 3.0's [type inference](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2007/02/local-variable-type-inference-in-c-30.html) (the new `var` keyword) to let the compiler infer the type:

```
var RandomInt = new RandomNumber();
```

(This is assuming you are using C# 3.0. Older versions do not have this feature.)

Lastly, as a style suggestion, you should make instances of classes start with a lowercase letter, to differentiate from actual classes, which start with capitals:

```
var randomInt = new RandomNumber();
```

Comment: Oh really? Thanks for the info on var. Cool feature.